# WPF: refresh a controls in other thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, invoke

I have simple WPF application where I using threads. E.g. In new thread I get DateTime and I want return it to the TextBox in main thread. I read to do this I must use ControlDispatcher.Invoke method. But something is wrong..

```
namespace Bizantyjskie
{
    public static class ControlExtensions
    {

        public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
        {
            if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread != control.Dispatcher.Thread)
                control.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
            else
                action();
        }
        public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this Control control, Action<T> action, T parameter)
        {
            if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread != control.Dispatcher.Thread)
                control.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, parameter);
            else
                action(parameter);
        }
    }

    class watki
    {
        public watki(MainWindow mw)
        {
            _mw = mw;
        }
        public MainWindow _mw;

        public void dzialaj()
        {
            Thread watek1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(w1));
            watek1.Start();
        }

        private void w1()
        {

            string godz = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
            ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired((value) => _mw.tb_w1.Text = value, godz);
        }
      }
     }
```

Problem is with

> ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired((value) => _mw.tb_w1.Text = value,
>   godz);

I got an error.

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Control' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Lambda syntax is wrong, you want something more along the lines of `ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired(() => { _mw.tb_w1.Text = godz });` though it depends what `InvokeIfRequired` requires for method signature, can you post the signature of that method? Are you just missing parenthesis? e.g. `ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired((value) => { _mw.tb_w1.Text = value }, godz);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling an extension method as a static one and forgetting to pass a parameter. Change it to this:

```
_mw.InvokeIfRequired(value => _mw.tb_w1.Text = value, godz);
```

Alternatively, if you still want to call it as a static method:

```
ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired(_mw, 
    value => _mw.tb_w1.Text = value, godz);
```

Comment: Good spot :) missed that one myself, been a long christmas with a lot of drinking

Comment: doesn't work. First one _mw it's controls object in MainWindow class, so I this object hasn't InvokeIfRequired method. Second one, I get an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Bizantyjskie.MainWindow'`

Comment: @user1031034 I updated my answer, it had a small typo. `InvokeIfRequired` is an extension method, so it can be called with the same syntax of an instance method from any class deriving from `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void w1()
{
    string godz = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
    ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired((value) => { _mw.tb_w1.Text = value; }, godz);
}
```

As I think your 'value' member is the parameter passed in to the delegate though I can't be sure without looking at the signature of `InvokeIfRequired` - if it's `object` won't you require a cast?

e.g.

```
ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired((value) => { _mw.tb_w1.Text = (string)value; }, godz);
```

---

**Edit:**

Sorry didn't even see the signature above! Looks like you are just missing the generic parameter to InvokeIfRequired:

```
ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired<string>((value) => { _mw.tb_w1.Text = value; }, godz);
```

That should work :)

The alternative is just to call the non-generic method and capture the string variable in the delegate scope:

```
ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired(() => { _mw.tb_w1.Text = godz; });
```

Which I think is a bit cleaner

Comment: The signature is up there, I believe 'public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this Control control, Action<T> action, T parameter)'

Comment: Argh, didn't even see that :D

Comment: None of the solutions listed above fix the problem.